# faceting with solr sunspot gem - facets quantity limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I use `sunspot` gem to work with solr.
I have faceted search results.

```
 <% @search.facet(:street_name).each ... %>
    ==> here only first 100 facets are rendering but it has to be more ( my city is big enough =) )
 <% end %>
```

In my rendered HTML now I have only the first 100 results of my facets collection (street names) but I need all of them. Is this some kind of limit either on solr or sunspot side?

How can i change it to 1000 for example if limiting is something here I can't disable?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/yPXwPtzJSLI)

here's the solution

```
Model.solr_search do

  facet :street_name, limit: 1000 # or -1 to switch off the limit at all

end
```

Comment: When I set `limit` to `-1`, it turns of the facets

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the sunspot doc here, https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Under the Facet section

By default Sunspot will only return the first 100 facet values. You can increase this limit, or force it to return all facets by setting limit to -1.

```
@search = Post.search do
  fulltext 'best pizza'
  facet :category_ids, :author_id
  limit -1
end
```

Comment: i hoped for a primer - piece of code - working solution... sunspot docs in this part not really transparent for understanding, but thank you for trying to help

Comment: unfortunately - this piece of code not working but i found the solution in sunspot google group... thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for the facet + limit syntax (it needed some parens):

`@search = Post.search do
  fulltext 'best pizza'
  facet(:category_ids, limit: -1)
end`